# error 0.0.2.0:0? below are the log

Tags: anonymity

```
09/11/2016 15:11:26 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:11:26 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:11:26 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:11:26 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 15:11:26 PM.200 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1"
09/11/2016 15:11:27 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09/11/2016 15:11:52 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 15:11:52 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:11:52 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 15:11:53 PM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
09/11/2016 15:13:05 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:13:05 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:13:05 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:13:05 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 15:13:12 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09/11/2016 15:17:48 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 3; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2) 
09/11/2016 15:17:48 PM.600 [WARN] 6 connections have failed: 
09/11/2016 15:17:48 PM.600 [WARN]  5 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
09/11/2016 15:17:48 PM.600 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
09/11/2016 15:17:58 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/11/2016 15:17:58 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/11/2016 15:17:58 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Can you view the page https://a0.awsstatic.com/ in a normal browser? (this is how meek-amazon should appear to some observer). It should give some "Access denied" error, but as long as it doesn't complain about a broken connection then there's no reason meek-amazon shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a SSL/TLS attack on your connection, try [Meek pluggable transport](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek) - it's desined specifically to deal with such kind of problems

Comment: i used meek amazon and azure but the same problem is persisting......showing error  0.0.2.0:0

Comment: try to set up your own meek server on some cheap VPS - to test the concept. If it will work - we will continue solving your problem in that direction. If it won't - then we will try another ways. Don't give up! We'll fix this!

Comment: thanks alexey for the help...i also  want to add that till this morning it was working fine with meek-amazon and i was able to connect the blocked content.. However, from today i m facing this trouble can my isp block tor..?  i have tried all the available transport but no luck in addition to that  mailed to get the obfs3 bridges and the error i got was socks failure.....

Comment: with this log file and taking in account that it was working with meek before - that's just one of the possible ways it is now... Try the test I posted upstrings - it will reveal this question's answer too